# spring batch write to ActiveMQ

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-batch, jmstemplate

I am try to write messages to a JMS queue which I take out in a next step to write to a database. The first part should be sync en the second async. The JMS part is really slow (1100 items to the queue in 1 minute).

This is how my job looks.

```
@Bean
public Job multiThreadedStepJob() { 
   Flow flow1 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("subflow1").from(step()).end(); 
   Flow flow2 = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("subflow2").from(step2()).end();
   Flow splitFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("splitflow")
   .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()).add(flow1, flow2) .build();

   return jobBuilders.get("multiThreadedStepJob")
                          .start(splitFlow).end().build();

}
```

The first step:

```
@Bean
public Step step() {
     return stepBuilders.get("step")
         .<OrderDTO, OrderDTO>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
         .reader(reader())
         .writer(writer())   
         .build();
}
```

the second step:

```
@Bean
public Step step2() {
    return stepBuilders.get("step2")
            .<OrderDTO, OrderDTO>chunk(100)
            .reader(reader2())
            .writer(writer2())
            .build();
}
```

I think that my errors are inside the writer of step and the reader of step2, because I can run the other reader and writer together and I have no problems.

```
@Bean
public JmsItemWriter<OrderDTO> writer() {
    JmsItemWriter<OrderDTO> itemWriter = new JmsItemWriter<>();
    itemWriter.setJmsTemplate(infrastructureConfiguration.jmsTemplate());
    return itemWriter;
}

@Bean
public JmsItemReader<OrderDTO> reader2() {
    JmsItemReader<OrderDTO> itemReader = new JmsItemReader<>();
    itemReader.setJmsTemplate(infrastructureConfiguration.jmsTemplate());
    itemReader.setItemType(OrderDTO.class);
    return itemReader;
}
```

They use the same JmsTemplate for connecting to the queue:

```
@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(queue());
    jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(500);
    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Bean
public Queue queue() {
    return new ActiveMQQueue("orderList");
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(BROKER_URL);
    factory.setTrustAllPackages(true);

    ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy prefetchPolicy = new ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy();
    prefetchPolicy.setQueuePrefetch(30);

    factory.setPrefetchPolicy(prefetchPolicy);

    PooledConnectionFactory pool = new PooledConnectionFactory(factory);
    pool.setMaxConnections(10);
    pool.setMaximumActiveSessionPerConnection(10);
    pool.isCreateConnectionOnStartup();

    return pool;
}
```

The rest of the configuration I use is the configuration from @EnableBatchProcessing. Does anyone know why this is going so slow?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently   jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true); is really important. This sped up the writing and reading from the JMS queue a great deal. From some reason I thought the default would be true, because I am working with batches.

Anyways if anyone else has this problem check this first, because it's easy to forget.